# How to convert String to int in C

Tags: c

I have following thing which i wanted to convert to int.

```
char *ptr; // this can point to variable length of string

int balance = functionToConverIntoint(ptr)
```

So is there any such function in C "functionToConverIntoint" which can do this job?

Comment: Did you even /try/ to search for this on stackoverflow?

Comment: Yeh i have but non of them were discussing C solution.

Comment: @itsaboutcode: that's just plain wrong. Sorry. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+string+to+int

Comment: Google also handles the question copied straight from the title.  Granted, the first answer advises atoi(), but whatever.  The Stack Overflow answer will be the first answer in a couple hours anyway.

Comment: More to the point, have you considered buying a C reference book or downloading a copy of the spec?  This is a very, very basic question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out strtol() and strtoul().

You want to avoid atoi() as it does not have a good way of distinguishing between a string of "0" and an invalid number.

Comment: strtol has 3 argument where is strtoul has 2 what i should enter in them?

Comment: Ok thanks i got it, can you tell me the function which can convert string to float?

Comment: @itsaboutcode: Where did you get this? Both `strtol` and `strtoul` take 3 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  `atoi` is a basic one with very limited error handling capability; `strtol` is a better one.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).

Comment: Unfortunately, `sscanf` offers no overflow protection. `strto...` is the only solution in this case.

Answer (score -2):

```
balance = atoi(ptr)
```