# C++ make a string to int function

Tags: c++

I usually program in python which has a string to integer converter built in but when i use C++ it doesn't seem to work so I decided to make my own.
this is what i made so far
C++:

```
int strtoint(string str)
{
    int values [str.length()];
    int return_value = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        if(str.at(str.length()-1-i) == '1')
            values[i] = 1;
        else if(str.at(str.length()-1-i) == '2')
            values[i] = 2;
        else if(str.at(str.length()-1-i) == '3')
            values[i] = 3;
        else if(str.at(str.length()-1-i) == '4')
            values[i] = 4;
        else if(str.at(str.length()-1-i) == '5')
            values[i] = 5;
        else if(str.at(str.length()-1-i) == '6')
            values[i] = 6;
        else if(str.at(str.length()-1-i) == '7')
            values[i] = 7;
        else if(str.at(str.length()-1-i) == '8')
            values[i] = 8;
        else if(str.at(str.length()-1-i) == '9')
            values[i] = 9;
    for (int i=0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        return_value += values[i]^(10*i);
    return return_value;
}
```

I seem to get very weird answers like `"12"` returns `13` and `"23"` returns `11`.

I know about `stoi` but I prefer to make my own so I can learn C++.

Comment: What's wrong with [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)?!

Comment: Or the old [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)?

Comment: C++11 doesn't work for me and like I said **I prefer to learn my own**

Comment: strtol isn't C++11... Also note that str.length() returns size_t, not int. And also you probably shouldnt be writing it 20 times in a single function :]. And make it guard against integer overflow. And make it work. All problems fading away when using the built-in functions..

Comment: @DrevanTonder Unless you can explain *how* it doesn't work, I, for one, see very little reason to help you reinvent that particular wheel.

Comment: If you want to do this as a learning exercise then I suggest you check an [ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii), because you don't need that long `if ... else if ...` chain. Try doing e.g. `'3' - '0'` and see what you get (the result is more or less guaranteed by the C++ specification).

Comment: I just can't get C++11 to work on my PC

Comment: @DrevanTonder If I were you I'd put my efforts into getting C++11 (or 14!) to work instead. You'll want it sooner or later.

Comment: I installed C++ with mingw yesterday.

Comment: _"I installed C++ with mingw "_ Now throw away bundled MinGW and download fresh build of MinGW-w64. IN the meantime you can check out glibc inmpementation of [`strtol`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/strtol.c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert String to int in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704411/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three problems I can see on a quick look.

The first is that

```
int values [str.length()];
```

is not valid C++.   It is using a feature from the 1999 C standard, which some C++ compilers support as an extension, but it is still not valid C++.

The second is lack of handling of `0`s or errors (non-digit characters) in input.

The third is the statement

```
return_value += values[i]^(10*i);
```

`^` is a bitwise XOR operator in C++.  Not mathematical exponentiation.

A couple of other minor tips.

You can probably simplify your code a lot by using iterators.

Also, with all standard character sets, the roman digits are sequential, starting with `'0'`.   So a simple way to convert a digit to the numeric value you want is   `digit - '0'`, which will convert `'0'` to `0`, `'1'` to `1`, .... `'9'` to `9`.

Comment: if I use pow it seems to work. I don't know how to use the iterator.

Comment: I wouldn't use `pow()`.  It's a really bad habit to use floating point operations when everything else involves integral values/types, even if it seems easier, because it exposes your code to other problems.    You have a loop which is running over digits.  A loop which does multiplication repeatedly can raise a value to an integer power.   So you can certainly use your loop to compute required powers of ten by introducing a simple multiplication.   Using iterators is something you need to read up and learn about.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ I use `std::stringstream` to convert `std::string` to `int`. Simple example I [found](http://code-better.com/c/convert-string-integer-using-stringstream):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>  //used for cout
int main()
{
    std::string str = "12345";
    std::istringstream ss(str);
    int i;
    ss >> i;
    if (ss.fail())
    {
        // Error
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The integer value is: " << i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Mistakes in your code you can find in @Peter answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this a lot with the char conversion where you just subtract the value of '0' and the use of iterators, especially reverse iterators which make it simpler to calculate the value.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

/*! Converts a char to an integer.
 * @param c the character to convert
 * @return the integer value [0-9] or -1 if not convertible
 */
int chartoint(const char c)
{
    auto value = (c - '0');
    if (value < 0 || value > 9)
    {
        value = -1;
    }
    return value;
}

/*! Converts a string to an integer.
 * @param string the string to convert
 * @return the converted integer value or 0 if not convertible
 */
int strtoint(const std::string& string)
{
    auto integer = 0;
    const auto begin = string.rbegin();
    for (auto it = begin, end = string.rend(); it != end; ++it)
    {
        const auto current = chartoint(*it);
        if (current == -1)
        {
            integer = 0;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            const auto factor = static_cast<int>(std::pow(10, (it - begin)));
            integer += factor * current;
        }
    }
    return integer;
}
```

Test run:

```
#include <cassert>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    assert(strtoint("1") == 1);
    assert(strtoint("1x") == 0);
    assert(strtoint("12") == 12);
    assert(strtoint("10") == 10);

    return 0;
}
```