# Error when attempting to iterate and print through an int ** that is in a structure

Tags: c, structure, c99

The error I receive when trying to print:

> threads: wcsrtombs.c:94: __wcsrtombs: Assertion `data.__outbuf[-1] ==
> '\0'' failed.
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

```
token = strtok(dup, delim);

while( token != NULL ){
  if( game->size >= game->capacity ){
    game->layout = (int**)realloc(game->layout, game->capacity*2 * sizeof(int*));
    game->capacity = game->capacity * 2;
  }

  game->layout[game->size] = (int*)token;
  game->size = game->size + 1;
  token = strtok(NULL, delim);
}
```

How int* are put into the int** in the structure called game.

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < game->size; i++ ){
  printf("%ls ", game->layout[i]);
  if(i == 0)
    continue;
  else if( (i+1) % 10 == 0 )
    printf("\n");
}
```

I changed the printing a bit to this code below. I now get output and no error, but the output is still wrong. I think it is possibly printing memory.

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < thisgame->size; i++ ){
  printf("%d ", *thisgame->layout[i]);
  if(i == 0)
    continue;
  else if( (i+1) % 10 == 0 )
    printf("\n");
}
```

My output:

> 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850
> 3276850 50  3276850 3538994 3538998 3604534 3604535 3604535 3473463
> 3473461 3276853 50  3276850 3604530 3604535 3604535 3276855 3276850
> 925958194 822097713 822097713 838874929  50 3276850 3276850 3276850
> 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850  50 3670072 3670072
> 3539000 3538998 3538998 3735606 3735609 3735609 3276857  50 3276850
> 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850  50
> 822095921 822095921 872427569 3407924 3735604 3735609 3735609 3276857
> 50  3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850
> 3276850 50  3342387 3342387 3538995 3538998 3538998 3735606 3735609
> 3735609 3276857 50  3342387 3342387 3538995 3538998 3538998 3735606
> 3735609 3735609 3276857 50  3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850
> 3276850 3276850 3276850 3276850 50

Comment: Seems like reasonable output for what you told the computer to do, which is to take the different parts of the string and pretend they're `int`s when they aren't.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704411/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-c ?

Comment: Bob, would you be able to take your program fragments, wrap them in a main() and provide the input data so somebody who wanted to help you would have a place to start?

Comment: `strtok` returns pointers into `dup`  , so if you ever execute the top code twice then you will end up with garbage

Comment: @M.M I execute strtok again but this time using NULL to get the next token in the string. I fixed the problem with my error, but I now get output with the first line being all 0s and the rest being all 10s

Comment: You should post a MCVE otherwise we are just guessing