# Why does my C code keeps crashing after multiplying this int?

Tags: c, char, crash, codeblocks

I compiled this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc == 2){
        printf("username: %s\n", argv[1]);
        int key = 0;
        key += (int)argv[1];
        printf("1\n");
        key = key * 2;
        char keyi = (char)key;
        printf("key: %s", keyi);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

(note that the printf("1\n"); is only for debugging)
it keeps crashing on the line where i multiply the key variable by 2.
i compiled it using codeblocks ide with the gnu gcc compiler.
Do you have any ideas of how to fix it?

i already debuged it using the x32gdb debugger but i couldnt find any compiler mistakes or any simalir things.

Comment: what are the arguments?

Comment: What do you think `key += (int)argv[1];` does?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert String to int in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704411/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-c)

Comment: `printf("key: %s", keyi);` keyi is a char, so this is wrong. Perhaps you want `%c`. Turn up your compiler warnings and I expect you will get a diagnostic about that mismatch. Do you know that keyi's value will be a printable character?

Comment: Your main problem is either that you haven't enabled warnings when you compile your program or that you have ignored them.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is crashing because of this line:

```
printf("key: %s", keyi);
```

`%s` is expecting a pointer to a null-terminated character string (`char[]` array). You are passing the value held in the `char` variable `keyi`, which is being treated converted to the pointer to `char`. This is *Undefined Behaviour*, which may express itself as a segfault.

The rest of the program is wrong as well. But it was explained by @AkashSingh_1 in his answer.

Comment: The `keyi` is a char, so the range of it is [-128, 127], which is probably not a valid address for both windows and *nix.

Comment: @Zwy it does not matter it can be even `uintptr_t` - but it will not after conversion reference a valid C string

Comment: I mean before printf realized if it's a valid c string or not, by dereferencing it, the printf crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Although you said you didn't find anything during debugging, if you did debug it, the code probably crashed at `printf("key: %s", keyi)`.
The reason is `%s` expect a string, which means a pointer to a valid address.
The type of `argv[1]` is `char *`, so you should not cast it to int with parentheses. If you expect to convert the content to int, you should call [`int atoi(const char *nptr)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html). By casting it to int directly, multiple it by 2 and cast it to char. Recall that range of char is [-128, 127], which is not in the valid address range of a user program. When `printf("key: %s", keyi)` tried to dereference it, it crashed.

And I'm not sure what you were trying to do with `char keyi = (char)key;`. But if you want to print the number out. You can just call `printf("key: %d", key)`. Or you can